# Image View that changes daily

Tags: android, image, kotlin

How would I do this? I have figured out how to change the image on a button click, but I would like the image to change automatically every midnight. A sort of daily image thing for my app. I'm not too sure how time works in kotlin and am entirely lost. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the WorkManager library for this. You can schedule a deferrable work. Check out the WorkManager documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager